# Why does Auth0 middleware redirects lead to 404 (page not found)?

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, auth0

This question is specific to Auth0 and Next.js.

[Following Auth0's example](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/blob/main/EXAMPLES.md#protecting-pages-with-middleware), I use this middleware to protect routes in a Next.js 13 application:

```
// middleware.js
import { withMiddlewareAuthRequired } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/edge";

export default withMiddlewareAuthRequired();

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/user/:path*", "/dashboard/:path*"],
};
```

When inspecting the live build with DevTools' Network tab, I see `404` (not found) errors on all calls to the Auth0 API login route (`/api/auth/login?returnTo=<some_path>`):

[image]

The above calls to the API login route happen when Next.js preloads a page as a result of a link to that page entering the browser viewport. It first tries to fetch the page directly (i.e. not via Auth0), then gets re-directed by the middleware (see above) to the login api route.

Oddly enough, this error does not happen in when hosting the production build locally via `npm run build` + `npm run start` (or in `npm run dev` for that matter).

**Why does this error happen, and how can I fix it?**

[Link to the Auth0 API on GitHub](https://auth0.github.io/nextjs-auth0/), in case helpful to readers.